# String forwardslash get replaced

Tags: java, regex, string

I am having below code

```
String outputStr = "-XX:-HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:MaxPermSize=64m -Xms24m -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.password.file=\"E:Java\\jmx-management\\jmxremote.password\" -Djava.awt.headless=true";

outputStr.replaceAll("-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.password.file=[\"\\w\\=\\.\\!\\#\\$\\%\\&\\*\\+\\-\\~\\:\\;\\,\\@\\|\\\\\\/]+",
    "-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.password.file=\"E:\\Java\\jmx-management\\jmxremote.password\"");
```

It is giving me

```
-XX:-HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:MaxPermSize=64m -Xms24m -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.password.file="E:Javajmx-managementjmxremote.password" -Djava.awt.headless=true
```

And I want this

```
-XX:-HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:MaxPermSize=64m -Xms24m -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.password.file="E:\Java\jmx-management\jmxremote.password" -Djava.awt.headless=true
```

without changing in replaceall

```
"-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.password.file=\"E:\\Java\\jmx-management\\jmxremote.password\""
```

Comment: Use 4 backslashes in the replacement string to denote 1 backslash.

Comment: Your title refers to "forwardslash [sic]", but your code sample contains no forward slashes. WTF?

Answer (score 1):

```
String outputStr = "-XX:-HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:MaxPermSize=64m -Xms24m -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.password.file=\"E:Java\\jmx-management\\jmxremote.password\" -Djava.awt.headless=true";
outputStr = outputStr.replace("\\\\", "\\");
```

Answer (score 0):

The main problem in your regex is that you need to use 4 backslashes in the Java replacement string literal to replace with 1 literal backslash. However, there are some more minor things that I'd like to comment:

- overescaping - most of the chars in the character class can be left unescaped as they are almost all treated as literal chars in a character class,
- the part of the pattern you want to keep can be *captured* and a backreference to it can be used in the replacement pattern making it shorter,
- dots must be escaped outside a character class to denote literal dots.

See [Java demo](https://ideone.com/OaVfwL):

```
String outputStr = "-XX:-HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:MaxPermSize=64m -Xms24m -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.password.file=\"E:Java\\jmx-management\\jmxremote.password\" -Djava.awt.headless=true";
outputStr = outputStr.replaceAll("(-Dcom\\.sun\\.management\\.jmxremote\\.password\\.file=)[-\"\\w=.!#$%&*+~:;,@|\\\\/]+",
    "$1\"E:\\\\Java\\\\jmx-management\\\\jmxremote.password\"");
System.out.println(outputStr);
// => -XX:-HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:MaxPermSize=64m -Xms24m -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.password.file="E:\Java\jmx-management\jmxremote.password" -Djava.awt.headless=true
```